# No audio with xubuntu + asus rog strix G17

Tags: sound, asus

after some struggle, got Xubuntu up and running on my asus laptop. Audio was fine after installation but after a reboot (possibly an update), I got sound no more.
Tried reinstalling alsa/pulseaudio + reload with no avail.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio; sudo alsa force-reload
```

Audio works fine on windows.

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to enable the audio but the volume control does not seem to work properly. It's either off or on. But something better than nothing.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add the following line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-no-sound-alc294-asus-rog-strix-512-ubuntu-20-04-01/

I ended up setting the default volume level using alsamixer